# Convert Custom Newitem form into PDF

Tags: web-part, event-receivers, pdf

I'm in a situation where i need to create an event receiver for a custom List, which will create a PDF file of Custom NewForm(replaced SharePoint default webpart with custom one for item adding) and save that PDF in a document library. So is there any way i can create a PDF of my Custom form when my item is added and then store that in Document Library?

Any help on this will be appreciated.